# Graph of the level set of a function

Tags: r

I want to plot the zero-set of function $f(x)=-x^2-y^2+z^2-1$. Can I do this in R, please? If so, how? More generally, how do I plot a function given a constraint, please? Thank you! If R does not work, what other software are good at such thing, please?

Comment: You have a function of three variables (x, y, and z). What sort of a plot were you envisioning? `filled.contour` can be used if you have a function that takes two variables as input.

Comment: The plot should be a 3-D graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
library(misc3d)
x = seq(-10, 10, 0.1)
y = seq(-10, 10, 0.1)
z = seq(-10, 10, 0.1)
f = function(x, y, z) -x^2-y^2+z^2-1
contour3d(f, 0 , x, y, z)
```